# Missing map for a specific company (esri)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, company-page

I followed a sponsored ad to see the [Esri company page on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/esri). Impressive. Scrolling down, I noticed something weird:

> [image]

So I went to a different company page, where I saw it should contain  a map, e.g. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/mediacrossing and just broken for esri.

I tried refreshing, hard refreshing. Nothing. No errors in console, no broken requests in the network tab. Nada.

Can the map be added to this company, or if by design, remove the huge blank area and unclickify the locations?

Comment: Probably a bit ironic given they are a GIS company after a bit of a look around on Careers they were the only company I could see with a broken map link.

Answer (score 3):

This was done by customer request.

Comment: Weird request. Would asking to change the design in this case be feasible? That huge gap and clickable text that does nothing when clicked doesn't look very good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard while just puzzling over this, I could image a situation where the marketing department could say "Our company location and information can only be presented using our technology" (poking about their [website](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/offices/minneapolis), this is certainly the case - that they *do* have web mapping technology (not that it should be a surprise) - note the watermark in the lower right corner there).  Brand use guidelines can be inflexible and strange to the outside observer... but hey if thats what they want.

Comment: @MichaelT yeah, this can explain the reason. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't involved in this bug fix, so I can't comment on the specifics, but I can agree that the missing image was probably a quick fix and looks like crap.  I'll bring this up on Monday and see if we can at least get some static image from them to replace it.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to post a feature request but if you'll put static image in there guess it will do.